# check if array is sorted and rotated

Tags: arrays, data-structures

The below code is for checking if the input was sorted and rotated by some position (including zero) would lead to the input array itself.

```
class Solution {
    public int [] rotate(int [] arr, int k){
        int [] ans = new int[arr.length];
        for(int i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
            ans[i]=arr[(i+k)%arr.length];
        }
        return ans;
    }

    public boolean check(int[] nums){
        int count=0;
        boolean b=false;
        for(int i=0;i<nums.length-1;i++){
            if(nums[i]<nums[i+1]){
                  b=true;;
            }
        }
        

        int [] temp = new int[nums.length];
        for(int i=1;i<nums.length;i++){
               temp=rotate(temp,i);
               for(int k=0;k<nums.length-1;k++){
                   if(temp[k]<temp[k+1]){
                     b=true;
                   }
               }
        }
      if(b==true){
          return true;
      }
   return false;
    }
}
```

The code returns `true` for the input `{2,1,3,4}` but the actual outcome should be `false`.

Comment: You are immediately setting your result to `true` once you encounter a single pair of values `arr[i]` and `arr[i+1]` where `arr[i] < arr[i+1]` ... Do it the other way around, ie initiallze your `b = true` and once you encounter an `arr[i] > arr[i+1]` set it to false.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to check whether you can derive a sorted array by just rotating the array the following algorithm is probably the simplest way to do so  (as you didn't tag a language, I used javascript, because this way you can immedately see the testcases executed. It should be quite easy to transform this into any other language)

```js
function check(arr) {
  let breaks = 0; 
  for (let i = 1; i < arr.length; i++){
    //check for broken ordering
    if (arr[i] < arr[i-1]) breaks++;
    //if you have more than one, the array cannot be sorted
    if (breaks > 1) 
      return false;
    //if you have encountered a break and the current value
    //is greater than the first one, the array cannot be sorted
    if (breaks && arr[i] > arr[0]) return false;
  }
  return true;
}


console.log("exp: true", check([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]));  //is already sorted
console.log("exp: true", check([4, 5, 1, 2, 3]));  //only one break
console.log("exp: true", check([4, 5, 1])); //only one break
console.log("exp: false", check([4, 5, 1, 2, 1]));  //two breaks
console.log("exp: false", check([4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 6]));  //value after break > than first
```

Ie you only need to iterate the array once. If you encounter a situation where a number `a[i]` is less than its predecessor `a[i-1]` you have situation where the ordering is broken. If you have more than one such breaks (for instance like in `5,6,3,4,1,2`) you cannot get a sorted array by just rotating. Furthermore, once you encountered such a break all values after this break have to be less than or equal to the very first element in the array. For instance `5,6,7,1,2,3` can be rotated, but `2,3,4,1,5` cannot.

Comment: could you pls explain why the specific comparison with `arr[0]` in - `arr[i] > arr[0]` ?

Comment: @subasri_ imagine an array like `4,5,6,1,2,7` when you try to rotate it until it's sorted ascending, the 4 of the original array will always end up to be after the 7 . Thus all values that are after the break in the original array must be less then the very first value, because otherwise the array still would not be sorted

Comment: got it, thank you

Answer (score 1):

I did some dry run and ran the code again although the time complexity is more but it still ran. Below is the code I implemented:

```
class Solution {
  public int [] rotate(int [] arr, int k) {
    int [] ans = new int[arr.length];
    for (int i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {
      ans[i] = arr[(i + k) % arr.length];
    }
    return ans;
  }

  public boolean check(int[] nums) {
    int count=0;
    for (int i=0; i<nums.length-1; i++) {
      if (nums[I] <= nums[i+1]) {
        count++;
      }
    }
    if (count == nums.length-1) {
      return true;
    }
    
    
    int [] temp = new int[nums.length];
    for (int i=1; i<nums.length; i++) {
      int count2 = 0;
      temp = rotate(nums, i);
      for (int k=0; k<nums.length-1; k++) {
        if (temp[k] <= temp[k+1]) {
          count2++;
        }
        if (count2 == nums.length-1) {
          return true;
        }
      }
    }
    return false;
  }
}
```